# Find needle within haystack in twig

Tags: twig

I want to check whether a certain word exists in a string. However, there's not other operator that exists which can do the job except containment operator. The following doesn't work to my utter frustration.

```
{% set deduction = 'Less Withholding Tax Thereon' %}
{% if 'Witholding' in deduction %}
    {% set test = "with" %}
{% else %}
    {% set test = "out" %}
{% endif %}
{{ test }}
```

Please see fiddle with various tests all amounting to same result
https://twigfiddle.com/00odoi

Comment: You're missing an `h` in the if statement. You wanted a double `h` in `Withholding`: `hh`.

Comment: OMG, this thing stressed me for like an hour I posted here and went to the gym to sweat it out